# Compare iOS Time Zone Rules

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nstimezone

If the user is in Eastern time, I don't want to display "EST" or "EDT" but if they are not, I do want to display it.

Is there an easy way to compare TimeZone rules in iOS?

`[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]` returns America/Indianapolis, but I just want to know if it is eastern.

Comparing data does not work, do I just compare `secondsFromGMT`?

**EDIT**
Comparing offsets does seem to work, but I don't know if it is going to cause problems later?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] abbreviation];` to get the abbreviation of whatever time zone the user is in.

This gives the abbreviation of the current date (EDT if not daylight savings and EST if daylight savings, in your case). If you want the abbreviation of a specific date, you can use `abbreviationForDate:` and insert any date.

[Here is some more information about NSTimeZone](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimeZone/abbreviation)

Edit:

If you want to actually compare multiple time zones (as in to check if it is the current time zone or not), you can use `isEqualToTimeZone:`. If that does not fit your needs, look at some of the other NSTimeZone methods in that link.

Comment: I think I read somewhere that isn't totally safe, because EST is present in both America and Australia?

Comment: @JDewzy The abbreviation for Australian Eastern Standard Time is [AEST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Australia)

Comment: Abbreviation is dependent upon locale.

Comment: So if it depends on locale, should it not be used? Or if it is highly unlikely someone outside the US is using my app, it's fine?

Comment: Try using `isEqualToTimeZone:` instead and compare it to the actual time zones.

Comment: @JDewzy You are absolutely correct, the 3-letter abbreviations are deprecated because they are not standardized. Using difference from GMT is much safer.

Comment: @Jsdodgers that does not work. You would have to compare it to every possible eastern time zone. US/Eastern and American/Indianapolis are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

I've had lots of pain from dealing with time zone issues on our tools app, that includes event scheduling across time zones.  The time zone names have not been friendly to use.  Also, Daylight savings time is a great big pain.

What has worked consistently for me is calls like this using timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT

I also convert my stored dates to GMT, then I can set them to the local time on display.

```
NSTimeZone *zone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
NSInteger timeZoneOffset = [zone secondsFromGMT];


[self.dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:timeZoneOffset]];
```

Comment: Do you always zero it out? Or was that just an example?

Comment: Sorry, that was an example of how I used it when normalizing all times to GMT for a particular project.  It was a bad example.

Comment: IF you edit your answer to more directly answer my question I'll accept it. Because according to Android, their "hasSameRules" method just counts seconds off GMT and that seems like what you were trying to get at? Or should I just post the solution I gathered from Android's website combined with what you said?

Comment: Feel free to post your solution.  But please don't use the Android solution!!!  (I think/hope you meant Apple's website, and not Android's)  I would love to see more info on this.

Comment: Haha, I did mean Android. Android has a "hasSameRules" method. Which is really what I want to do. Here is a link:http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#hasSameRules(java.util.TimeZone). It says it just compares offsets. So I was going to use that same logic. So my solution, was creating two NSTimeZones, two ints of the offsets, and comparing the two ints.